# RubyMine shows error when try to run the project it says that cant find rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubymine

when trying to start Ruby project in the RubyMine I got following error message

[image]

my environment is:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.3

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]

$ bundle info rails
  * rails (5.2.3)
        Summary: Full-stack web application framework.
        Homepage: http://rubyonrails.org
        Path: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails-5.2.3

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.2.14
```

[image]

Tools => Show Gem Environment =>

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
RUBY VERSION: 2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/semyuel/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.7
GIT EXECUTABLE: /bin/git
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/semyuel/.gem/specs
SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
   /home/semyuel/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
   /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.7.0
   /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.7.0
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   https://rubygems.org/
SHELL PATH:
   /bin
   /usr/local/bin
   /opt/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64/bin
   /home/semyuel/.local/bin
   /usr/local/sbin
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/sbin
   /usr/bin
   /sbin
   /bin
   /usr/games
   /usr/local/games
   /snap/bin
----------------------
IDE: RubyMine 2020.3.3, build #RM-203.7717.69
OS: Linux 5.8.0-48-generic[amd64]
Java: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: ruby-2.7.0-p0
Sdk Version: ver.2.7.0p0 ( revision 647ee6f091) p0
Ruby Interpreter: /bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: System RubySdk Language Level: 2.7
Sdk Load Path:
     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.7.0
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.7.0
     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.7.0
     /snap/rubymine/217/plugins/ruby/rubystubs/rubystubs27
Sdk Gem paths: 
     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems
     /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems
     ~/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems
     /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.7.0/gems
     /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.7.0/gems
     /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems
     ~/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems
     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler/gems
     /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.7.0/bundler/gems
     /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/bundler/gems
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.7.0/bundler/gems
Gems used for 'proj':
```

I can see that the current `bundler` version is different than the specified in the settings but I'm not sure how to fix that and whether it's the reason of that error. Please advice.

current `Bundler` version is 2.2.14
however, in the settings I see that `bundler` version is 2.1.2

Comment: You can see in the settings image you posed "rails" is not in the list or the right hand side. This means rails is not installed for 2.7.0. `2.7.0 (2019-12-25 patchlevel 0)` is not the same as `ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c)`. **Solutions:** either (a) add the 2.7.1 to ruby mine and assign it for this project; or (b) run gem install rails under 2.7.0.

Comment: @ingineersmnky adding ruby 2.7.1 solved the problem